# difficulty to deal with $\min(n,\frac{1}{x})$ in a problem that asks to prove $\{f_n\}_n$ is not uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> $\{f_n\}_n$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$, where
>
> $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} \min(n, \frac{1}{x}) & \textrm{ if } 0<x\leq 1 \\ 0 & \textrm{ if } x=0  \end{cases}.\bigg\}, \space n\in \mathbb{N}$$

I am not sure whether my approach correctly proves that $\{f_n\}$ is not uniformly convergent in $[0,1]$. Specifically, I need to know the way I treated $\min(n,\frac{1}{x})$ whether is correct or wrong.

Here is my approach to prove the problem-

If I'm not wrong then $f_n(x)=\min(n,\frac{1}{x})$ records the lowest value of $n$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ and therefore either $n<\frac{1}{x}$ or $\frac{1}{x}<n$

at $x\to 0, \space f_n(0)=\min(n,\frac{1}{x})\to \infty$ which is meaningless and not sure even if it is pointwise convergent because $$\lim_{n \to\infty}f_n(x)|sup_{x\in(0,1]}\to \infty$$. So there is no sign of uniform convergence or point-wise convergence.

Hence - using cauchy sequence I get, $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\\\Longrightarrow |\mid n-\frac{1}{x}\mid-\infty|<\epsilon$$ which is absurd iff the assumption $lim_{n\to\infty}\min(n,\frac{1}{x}) \to \infty$ is acceptable. Hence no uniform convergence.

Also there is an explicit formula for which is given as $$\min(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg [x+y-|y-x|\Bigg]$$ but using this formula for $\min(n,\frac{1}{x})$ makes the problem more complicated.

Due to the little knowledge on dealing with this kind of problem I ask for any suggestion or any alternate process to prove this. Any help is precious and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't put infinities in absolute values and don't use it in arithmetic. Don't divide by zero. "limits as $n$ tends to $∞$" is defined without defining $∞$. If you look at the definition, $f_n(0)$ is defined to be $0$ separately from the values $f_n(x)$ for $x>0$. In particular $f_n(0)$ is defined without reference to any minimum. I also have trouble understanding what $ \lim_{n \to\infty}f_n(x)|_{x\in(0,1]}\to ∞$ means. Did you forget to add a supremum?

Comment: Oh, there is a mistake then. Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: You're welcome. You should find pointwise convergence to some function(which you should find), without uniform convergence. I would suggest drawing $f_n$ for $n=,1,2,3$.

Comment: You can observe that $\lvert f(1/2n) - f_n(1/2n)\rvert = \lvert 2n - n\rvert = n$ for all $n \ge 2$. Thus for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can never have $\lvert f(x) - f_n(x) \rvert < \epsilon$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ (which would be required it the sequence converged uniformly).

Comment: @CalvinKhor, If $f_1=(1,\frac{1}{x}), f_2=(2,\frac{1}{x}),...$ and in this way $n$ goes to $\infty$. And to find pointwise limit we use $lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ and $f_(x) \to \infty$. May be I cannot catch your last clue (and hence I am wrong).

Comment: @thevbm sorry but I don't understand this comment. I have issue with $x$ appearing on one side of an equation only. Also $f_n(x)$ does not tend to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity, for *any* value of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the term $f_n$ can be rewritten as follows:

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 
n & \textrm{ if } 0<x\leq \frac{1}{n} \\ 
\frac{1}{x} & \textrm{ if } \frac{1}{n} <x\leq 1 \\ 
0 & \textrm{ if } x=0  
\end{cases}.$$

From a point-wise point of view, when $n$ goes to $+\infty$, then the limit of the sequence is:

$$f(x) =\begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{x} & \textrm{ if } 0 <x\leq 1 \\ 
0 & \textrm{ if } x=0  
\end{cases}.$$

Now consider the following:

$$f_n(x) - f(x)=\begin{cases} 
n-\frac{1}{x} & \textrm{ if } 0<x\leq \frac{1}{n} \\ 
0 & \textrm{ if } \frac{1}{n} <x\leq 1 \\ 
0 & \textrm{ if } x=0  
\end{cases}.$$

Then:

$$\sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = \sup_{x \in \left(0, \frac{1}{n}\right]} \left|n - \frac{1}{x}\right| = +\infty.$$

This means that your sequence does not converge uniformly to the function $f(x)$.

Comment: The rewriting part you have provided - that's what i needed to know. I did not know that it can be rewritten in this way and here I was stuck. The rest of the part is now easy to understand. Thank you for this clear and nice approach. (+1)

Comment: Your are welcome. Notice that, given $a>0$ and $b>0$, then: $$\min(a,b) = \frac{1}{\max\left(\frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{b}\right)}$$

Comment: This formula you provided is new and helpful to me. I have gone through several examples of uniform convergence but never came across with this formula. Would you like to suggest which part of calculus deal with the algebra of this $\min(a,b) = \frac{1}{\max\left(\frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{b}\right)}$ because I'm excited to learn this.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $f_n$ *does* converge pointwise to
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\frac1x&x\in(0,1]\\
0&x=0
\end{array}\right.
$$
This is *not* continuous, but neither are the $f_n$, so we can't draw a contradiction from this.

If $f_n$ is [uniformly convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence), then for any $\epsilon\gt0$, there needs to be an $N$ so that if $n,m\ge N$, then for all $x$,
$$
|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\le\epsilon
$$
However,
$$
f_{n+1}\!\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)-f_n\!\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)=1
$$

Comment: Would you please suggest me how to rewrite $f_{n+1}(\frac{1}{n+1})$, so I can understand your hint in details?

Comment: According to the definition, $f_{n+1}\!\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)=n+1$, but $f_n\!\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)=n$.

Comment: Thank you and I have learnt something new. Thank you again.